# Renaming Azure Active Directory

Tags: azure, active-directory, azure-active-directory

Currently I have an Active Directory associated with a set of subcriptions for the company I work at's Azure platform. However, the 'Default Directory' AD is on the domain `forenamesurnamehotmailco` where `forenamesurname` is an employee that no longer works here.

My question is twofold:

- Does renaming the directory from 'Default Directory' possibly break any links that are possibly hard-coded anywhere *(assume poor legacy code quality)* (connection strings etc.), or is it a superficial name that i can change freely?
- Does changing the *domain* name from `forenamesurnamehotmailco` to something else have any possible unintended consequences?

Thank you.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Q: "Does renaming the directory from 'Default Directory' possibly break anything?"

You can modify the directory name of Azure AD based on your requirements. It's just a display name, which will show up on the login page. The name modification will not break any links.

Q: "Does changing the domain name have any possible unintended consequences?"

The initial domain name was established when the directory was created by the admin, and **it can't be changed or deleted**. However, you can add a custom domain name.

Please see the referred part from official documentation below.

> Every domain name in Azure AD is either an initial domain name, or a
> custom domain name.
>
> Every Azure AD comes with an initial domain name in the form
> contoso.onmicrosoft.com. This third level domain name, in this example
> “contoso.onmicrosoft.com,” was established when the directory was
> created, typically by the admin who created the directory. The initial
> domain name for a directory can't be changed or deleted. The initial
> domain name, while fully functional, is intended primarily to be used
> as a bootstrapping mechanism until a custom domain name is verified.

Comment: This is pretty terrible (that it cannot be changed) as the name becomes your SharePoint Online domain name, so forenamesurnamehotmailco.sharepoint.com.

Comment: For anyone else searching, modifying the directory **name** is simply from the "Properties" section of the "Azure Active Directory" blade - currently at https://portal.azure.com/#blade/Microsoft_AAD_IAM/ActiveDirectoryMenuBlade/Properties

Comment: Thanks @ClaireFurney, I saw this answer and still had to hunt for it as I didn't see your comment - I've added details and a screenshot to the original answer, edits should be visible soon if approved.

Comment: @pcdev np - glad I wasn't the only one ;-