# Is it possible to rename an Azure subscription name/domain?

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-network

Here's a screenshot of one of our current Azure subscriptions:

[image]

Is it possible to rename the domain for .. say `Pew pew #1` from `someLameLoginUserAccount.onmicrosoft.com` to `purekrome-pewpew1.onmicrosoft.com`

(assumption: that FQDN isn't 'taken' on .. I guess Azure AD).

Comment: No, it is not possible. Please refer to this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42276712/renaming-azure-active-directory/42289913#42289913).

Comment: @Walter-MSFT - ok. great answer link btw. Is it possible to add a new custom AD and then drop/delete this `***.onmicrosoft.com` AD? NOTE: this is before _any_ resource is created/add.

Comment: For anyone stumbling here trying to find out how to rename one of your multiple default `Pay-As-You-Go` subscriptions, it is possible - select "View My Bill", select the Subscription, Manage, Edit Subscription Details, and you can give your subscription a friendly name. [More here](http://rickrainey.com/windows-azure-how-tos/how-to-change-the-name-of-your-windows-azure-subscription/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not possible. Please refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42276712/renaming-azure-active-directory/42289913#42289913).

> Is it possible to add a new custom AD and then drop/delete this
>   ***.onmicrosoft.com AD? NOTE: this is before any resource is created/add.

No, it is also impossible, you could create custom AD, but you could not delete the default Azure AD directory(***.onmicrosoft.com).

Comment: Cheers. Why would a person want to create a custom AD, then?

Comment: When you create custom AD, this allows you to assign user names in the directory that are familiar to your users, such as ‘alice@contoso.com.’  Maybe this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-domains-add-azure-portal) is helpful. Notes: The domain should be registered on the public network.