# Azure MSDN Subscription: change the url of the default AD

Tags: powershell, azure

By default, you get an AD which is associated with your azure subscription which is identified by name on the form XXX.onmicrosoft.com. Does anyone know if it's possible to change the XXX to something else?

Thanks.

Luis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it is not possible.

You could create a new AD account or add or custom domain to Azure AD, please check my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44103418/is-it-possible-to-rename-an-azure-subscription-name-domain/44104867#44104867) about this.

Comment: Hello Walter. Thanks for the reply. I really don't remember why, but I've ended up with a new domain with the name ***hotmail.onmicrosoft.com associated with my MSDN subscription and I really would love to remove the hotmail word from it. Unfortunately, that isn't possible...